# react native running on vagrant box

Tags: react-native, vagrant

I setup a vagrant box to be my react native dev environment, connected my android phone on USB in debug mode but react native cannot find my device.

```
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

How can I make it possible for my device to be recognized?

Comment: Did you switch on the developer option if available from the settings?

Comment: What do you mean? Where is this option you are referring to?